# Cannot find module './components/home/home.module.ngfactory' on production build

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

It's a bit long post, I tried to include everything that can be related. My environment is .Net Core 2.0 with Angular 5 and webpack.

My application is working perfectly on development with all its content. I have no problem or any error. But when I publish my application (production build) I am getting error from angular.

I get error on lazy loading.

I think there is something I miss for my production config or something weird is happening due the libraries.

I wrote the error and the part at the end, i also included every config file.

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: isDevBuild ? /\.ts$/ : /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                { test: /\.(ts|js)$/, use: 'angular-router-loader' },
                { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
                { test: /\.scss$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize', 'sass-loader'] },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule')
                })
            ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
};
```

webpack.config.vendor.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const treeShakableModules = [
    '@angular/animations',
    '@angular/common',
    '@angular/compiler',
    '@angular/core',
    '@angular/forms',
    '@angular/platform-browser',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
    '@angular/router',
    'zone.js'
];
const nonTreeShakableModules = [
    'bootstrap',
    'core-js/client/shim',
    'web-animations-js',
    'event-source-polyfill',
    'jquery',
    '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/assets/icons.css',
    'ng2-toasty',
    'ng2-toasty/bundles/style-bootstrap.css',
    'ng2-charts',
    'ngx-bootstrap/modal',
    'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip',
    'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown',
    'bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.css',
    'bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.js',
    'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css',
    'bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js',
    'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css',
    'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'
];
const allModules = treeShakableModules.concat(nonTreeShakableModules);

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: { extensions: ['.js'] },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(gif|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' }
            ]
        },
        output: {
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular\b.*\b(bundles|linker)/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/, path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp')), // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14898
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^vertx$/) // Workaround for https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise/issues/100
        ]
    };

    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            // To keep development builds fast, include all vendor dependencies in the vendor bundle.
            // But for production builds, leave the tree-shakable ones out so the AOT compiler can produce a smaller bundle.
            vendor: isDevBuild ? allModules : nonTreeShakableModules
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist') },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract({ use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }) }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig];
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true, // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17863. Remove this if you upgrade to a fixed version of Angular.
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "webpack-env" ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "sahatakip",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^5.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.9.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^11.1.4",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.3",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bootstrap-datepicker": "^1.7.1",
    "bootstrap-select": "^1.12.4",
    "bootstrap-toggle": "^2.2.2",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.2",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.13.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.5",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.21.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.0.8",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.2",
    "angular-router-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-webpack": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev-build": "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js",
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  }
}
```

boot.browser.ts

```
import 'core-js/client/shim';
import 'web-animations-js';
import 'zone.js';
import 'bootstrap';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
const rootElemTagName = 'app-root';

if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept();
    module.hot.dispose(() => {
        //const oldRootElem = document.querySelector(rootElemTagName);
        //const newRootElem = document.createElement(rootElemTagName);
        //oldRootElem.parentNode.insertBefore(newRootElem, oldRootElem);
        platform.then(appModule => appModule.destroy());
    });
} else {
    enableProdMode();
}
// Boot the application, either now or when the DOM content is loaded
let platform = platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
platform.then(() => { (<any>window).appBootstrap && (<any>window).appBootstrap(); })
```

Routing Sample:

```
{ path: '', loadChildren: './components/home/home.module#HomeModule' }
```

Until this part, everything works fine when i build with below commands:

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
```

But when i use production build as below:

```
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod
node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod
```

and when i try to navigate this compiled content, it throws, below error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './components/home/home.module.ngfactory'.
    at vendor.js?v=_76xaipghoKW6rrUpx3wrzV0og1-XYyjex-gA5TYo6o:249
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41100)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js?v=_76xaipghoKW6rrUpx3wrzV0og1-XYyjex-gA5TYo6o:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41099)
    at Zone.run (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:40850)
    at main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41581
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41133)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js?v=_76xaipghoKW6rrUpx3wrzV0og1-XYyjex-gA5TYo6o:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41132)
    at Zone.runTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:40900)
    at vendor.js?v=_76xaipghoKW6rrUpx3wrzV0og1-XYyjex-gA5TYo6o:249
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41100)
    at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js?v=_76xaipghoKW6rrUpx3wrzV0og1-XYyjex-gA5TYo6o:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41099)
    at Zone.run (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:40850)
    at main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41581
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41133)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js?v=_76xaipghoKW6rrUpx3wrzV0og1-XYyjex-gA5TYo6o:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41132)
    at Zone.runTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:40900)
    at resolvePromise (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41532)
    at resolvePromise (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41503)
    at main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41581
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41133)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js?v=_76xaipghoKW6rrUpx3wrzV0og1-XYyjex-gA5TYo6o:36)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41132)
    at Zone.runTask (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:40900)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (main-client.js?v=WzTp96NIkmPUksemtcBC-ufCfRmAt1uBd5ohqiM-yys:41310)
    at <anonymous>
```

Comment: Change your lazy loaded routes to be relative to the app root. e.g. `'app/components/home/home.module#HomeModule'`.

Comment: when i do that, webpack build command throws below error:


`Could not resolve module components/home/home.module relative to X:/Y/Z/Z/Z/ClientApp/app/app-routing.module.ts`

Comment: I took the advice from [here](https://angular.io/guide/router#lazy-loading-route-configuration), so I can't help any further. Good luck.